# Ajax Registration Form ins't validating rules

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation

I have a registration form that has rules to check before letting the form submit. Such as min, max length. However when I fill the form and submit the content goes in without validating. I can have usernames that are 1 character long when they should not be.

```
$(function(){

var form    = $('form');
var submit  = $('#submit');
var alert   = $('.alert');

// validate form
form.validate({
    // validation rules
    rules: {
        // name field (required , minimum length 3)
        name: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 3
        },
        // username field (required , minimum length 3, max 8)
        username: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 3,
            maxlength: 8,
        },
        // password field (required , minimum length 6, max 16)
        password: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 6,
            maxlength: 16
        },
        // password2 field must be equal to password field
        password2: {
            equalTo: '#password'
        },
        // email field only required
        email: 'required'
    },
    // submit ajax request
    submitHandler: ajaxSubmit
});

/**
* ajax submit function
* sending simple ajax request
**/

function ajaxSubmit() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://codegamer.net/registration/ajax.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        // form serialize data
        data: form.serialize(),
        beforeSend: function(){
            alert.fadeOut();
            submit.val('Sending...').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        },
        success: function(data){
            if ( data.status === 'success' ) {
                // if response status == success redirect to success page
                $(location).attr('href','success.html');
            } else {
                // not success! show error messages
                alert.html(data.status).fadeIn();
                submit.val('Sign Up').removeAttr('disabled');
            }
        },
        error: function(){
            // show error message
            alert.html('Sending request fail').fadeIn();
            submit.val('Sign Up').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
};
});
```

I am new to jQuery, AJAX, PHP so I am learning along the way.

Comment: Do you correctly include the validation plugin? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. This was a premade form that I got off the internet. I have a validation.min.js file but it is not formatted properly.

Comment: The validation.min.js is the plugin you're using for validation. Send us the source of that so we can look at what's going wrong. Also the .min in the name means it's been minified. You can probably find a uncompressed version from the plugin author.

Comment: I guess you're using this http://jqueryvalidation.org/ Anyway make sure you include the JavaScripts in the right order (first jQuery then the validation.min.js). If you're using Chrome press F12 and click on Console and tell us if you see any messages there.

Comment: http://codegamer.net/registration/assets/js/validation.min.js
That is the validation. I cant find the unminimized one in the github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of potential issues here, make these changes and we'll see if there are any other problems.

`var form    = $('form');
var submit  = $('#submit');
var alert   = $('.alert');`

You are assigning these to another variable, which is good, but you should still wrap the variable with the jquery: $(). I updated it throughout the code and posted it below.

This form selector won't return anything based on what I saw on your site:

`var form    = $('form');`

Give the form a unique id and use the id selector $(#), same as you did with the submit button, or you can just use the class that's already there. Copy this into your script.js file:

```
$(function(){

var form    = $('form.form-horizontal');
var submit  = $('#submit');
var alert   = $('.alert');

// validate form
form.validate({
    // validation rules
    rules: {
        // name field (required , minimum length 3)
        name: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 3
        },
        // username field (required , minimum length 3, max 8)
        username: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 3,
            maxlength: 8,
        },
        // password field (required , minimum length 6, max 16)
        password: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 6,
            maxlength: 16
        },
        // password2 field must be equal to password field
        password2: {
            equalTo: '#password'
        },
        // email field only required
        email: 'required'
    },
    // submit ajax request
    submitHandler: ajaxSubmit
});

/**
* ajax submit function
* sending simple ajax request
**/

function ajaxSubmit() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        // form serialize data
        data: form.serialize(),
        beforeSend: function(){
            alert.fadeOut();
            submit.val('Sending...').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        },
        success: function(data){
            if ( data.status === 'success' ) {
                // if response status == success redirect to success page
                $(location).attr('href','success.html');
            } else {
                // not success! show error messages
                alert.html(data.status).fadeIn();
                submit.val('Sign Up').removeAttr('disabled');
            }
        },
        error: function(){
            // show error message
            alert.html('Sending request fail').fadeIn();
            submit.val('Sign Up').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
};

});
```

Comment: Like I said, I am new to jQuery and AJAX and this was premade. I have no clue really what needs to be done. Thanks though.

Comment: Ok, some of this is just general programming stuff. I have an alternative in mind, let me know if you can edit this file and I'll post it: http://codegamer.net/registration/assets/js/script.js

Comment: Updated the answer above, that should do it.

Comment: Still went through. I am starting to think it might be another file. I am also thinking about just reworking my project without a registration.

Comment: Works when I checked your site. Hit Ctrl+F5 or the refresh button in your browser to make sure you refresh all the included scripts.

Comment: Oh nice. I did the refresh and it works :). Now just need to figure out regex to make the password more secure and ill be set!